# Saved Excel Document as a Text (Tab Delimited) file. Then renamed to .tsv. Now it shows filename.txt.tsv. How do I get rid of the .txt part?

Tags: excel, file, csv

Needing to upload this file and it needs to be in .tsv format. I saved the excel file as a text (tab delimited file). Went and renamed it to .tsv, and it switched to an excel icon (from a text pad). But when I went to upload it the developer shot me a note that said it shouldn't say both .txt and .tsv. Only .tsv. When I looked at the file properties it says "Filetype: Text" still. I'm not sure what I should be doing here.

[This is how it looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w2uJg.png)

Comment: Try using Save As, select "Text (Tab delimited)" as the file type, and in the "File name" field add .tsv to the end of the name, then hit Save.

Comment: Thanks. I did that but that's what got me to the issue I am in now.

Answer (score -1):

Changing the file extension manually won’t change the format of the file contents. You need to open the file in excel click save as and select the correct file type from the drop down box below file name input section

Comment: Thank you. But the only option out of excel is Text (tab delimited). How would I be able to save directly as a .tsv?

Comment: Excel cannot saves files as .tsv by default.